# for loop to retrieve checkbox in gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, checkbox

I have this problem with the checkbox (inside gridview) and I had been searching on net and cracking my brain to counter this problem..

What i have now is that,

(this is my gridview)

```
id   amount($)   
1    5         checkbox 
2    13        checkbox
3    25        checkbox
```

I have an initial value (example $1000). whenever I check on checkbox inside the gridview, it would minus from the initial value. 
if i check on id=1, the initial value would be deducted and show $995.

if i continue to check on another checkbox let's say id=3 (so now i have 2 checkbox that are checked), the amount would display $970 now.

Currently, it worked out fine for the first checkbox checked, however subsequent checkboxes are giving my problems.. instead of deducting $25, it deduct $30 (25+5)

Here is my code:

```
  protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox selectChk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1");

        if (selectChk != null && selectChk.Checked)
        {
            String amount = ((Label)row.FindControl("amt")).Text;

            double amtSpend = Convert.ToDouble(usedSpace);

            double left = 100 - amtSpend;
            totalLbl.Text = left.ToString();


        }
```

i was thinking that, because it was inside a for loop, that's why everytime the 2nd checkbox is check, it would run the whole for loop again, and it would include the amount of the 1st checkbox. is that anyway i can solve this? (likewise for the 3rd checkbox, it would include the amt in 1st and 2nd checkbox)

Or is there any method that i can get the particular row of the gridview with checkbox checked without using for loop?

Comment: I think you might have used same name "Checkbox1" for every check box in each row of the grid, hence for every row in grid, it is getting the checkbox1 and doing as per your code.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
     CheckBox chk = row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as CheckBox;
     if (chk != null && chk.Checked)
     {
           // ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using a datasource of a class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged so you dont have to iterate through all rows and state. The setter 'Checked' gets fired when the checkbox changes the state so you can subtract the amount inside that setter.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WindowsFormsApplication9.Annotations;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication9
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingList<Entity> entities = new BindingList<Entity>();
            entities.Add(new Entity {Amount = 10.0, Checked = false, Id = 1});
            entities.Add(new Entity {Amount = 900.0, Checked = false, Id = 2});
            entities.Add(new Entity {Amount = 850.0, Checked = false, Id = 3});

            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = entities;
        }
    }

    public class Entity : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _bChecked;
        private double _dAmount;
        private int _iId;

        public int Id
        {
            get { return this._iId; }
            set
            {
                if (value == this._iId)
                    return;

                this._iId = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public double Amount
        {
            get { return this._dAmount; }
            set
            {
                if (value == this._dAmount)
                    return;

                this._dAmount = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool Checked
        {
            get { return this._bChecked; }
            set
            {
                if (value == this._bChecked)
                    return;

                this._bChecked = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
                // Change the value 10 to the value you want to subtract
                if (value) this.Amount = this._dAmount - 10;
            }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}



[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
  public sealed class NotifyPropertyChangedInvocatorAttribute : Attribute
  {
    public NotifyPropertyChangedInvocatorAttribute() { }
    public NotifyPropertyChangedInvocatorAttribute(string parameterName)
    {
      ParameterName = parameterName;
    }

    public string ParameterName { get; private set; }
  }
```